# Floating left and inline-block working for only some elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use inline/inline-block to get a simple two row layout but it's not working for my third element. I want the top row to have three pictures and the bottom row to have text under each picture that the text pertains to. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```css
.floatL {
  float: left;
}

.box div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <div class="floatL">
    <img src="dog1.jpg" alt="Picture of a Dog" width="100" height="100">
    <p>Something about the dog</p>
    </img>

  </div>

  <div class="floatL">
    <img src="cat1.jpeg" alt="Picture of a Cat" width="100" height="100">
    <p>Something about the dog</p>
    </img>
    <div class="floatL">

      <img src="colors1.jpg" alt="Picture of Colors" width="100" height="100">
      <p>Something about the dog</p>
      </img>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Johannes says, the third floated element was nested.

You need to properly indent, and you will catch these more easily.

Also, you don't use closing tags on `img`.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yg8ysea/) for a refactor of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your third `.floatL` element is inside the second one - put a closing DIV tag before the opening tag of the third one.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize for that blunder.

Comment: No need to apologise @Shinji, just upvote if its helpful. That's the only responsibility you have! There's such a thing as being too apologetic when in an environment that welcomes questions!! ;)